in Python how to disable the "Task was destroyed but it is pending!" warning
As I understand it : if an asyncio task is waiting on a future and this future is destroyed by the garbage collector then the task is destroyed too. Which is great because the task would never have completed anyway because the future will never have a result.
This behavior makes total sense, I might have in my program futures that are destroyed and I like that the tasks that could be waiting on them will not cause memory leak by sticking around. How can I get rid of the warning message "Task was destroyed but it is pending!" that is printed in the console each time this happens ?
Here is a code example, everything is working as-intended in my opinion except for the annoying "Task was destroyed but it is pending!" messages in the console.
import asyncio
import os
import psutil
import random
import gc
import time

async def waitForEvent(e: asyncio.Event):
    # Generate a 1MB array of random bytes to see memory leaks
    rand_seq = random.getrandbits(8)
    random_bytes = bytearray(rand_seq for _ in range( 1024 * 1024))
    await e.wait()
    print("event completed", random_bytes[-10:])  # Print the last 10 bytes

events = []
def startDeadCoroutine():
    ev = asyncio.Event()
    #events.append(ev) uncomment this to see that the task is no longer destroyed because the event is no longer eligible for garbage collection
    asyncio.create_task(waitForEvent(ev))
        
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
async def main():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    while True:
        startDeadCoroutine()
        mem_info = process.memory_info()
        print(f"Memory usage: {mem_info.rss / 1024 / 1024:.2f} MB")
        gc.collect()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # Add a delay

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


Your assumptions are not correct. (1) If a task is awaiting a future, then the future is referenced by the task and cannot be garbage collected. (2) The "destroyed task" warning occurs when the event loop is closed when there still exist unfinished tasks. Your code is incomplete and not runnable (await outside of an async func is a syntax error). Please post a minimal and reproducible code in order to get a better feedback from the SO community.

I run this inside a standard jupyter notbook cell I guess notbook cells are async functions. I'll edit with a .py equivalent

It looks to me my code proves that you are wrong when you state "If a task is awaiting a future, then the future is referenced by the task and cannot be garbage collected"

@Fogux, ...keep in mind, the fact that the task references the future if it's awaiting it is only relevant if the task itself is reachable for gc purposes. In your code that's not true.

Anyhow -- have you tried using Python's warnings framework? Controlling which warnings you want to suppress is exactly what it's there for.
